# How do I force refresh of a yodlee site_account?

Tags: yodlee

Using the Yodlee API, if I have a successfully connected site_account, and then something changes (say the user updates the answers to their MFA questions) causing refresh to give Yodlee an error, how do I force it to refresh so that I can retry entering MFA information? Using startSiteRefresh I can't get it to force refresh, even with forceRefresh on RefreshParameters set to True. All I get back is SiteRefreshStatus=None with the previous error code, and it doesn't let me ask for new mfa questions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, if you want to change the values like username, password, Q&A for MFA, you can use the updateCredentialsForItem call to edit the item. You can then refresh the account.

More details on [this page](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/SOAP_API_Reference/updateCredentialsForItem).

Comment: Based on the wsdls provided and by virtue of the fact that that includes startRefreshOnUpdate I think the API call in that faq is for updateCredentialsForItem1. In any case, upon completion of this will it refresh the item or site? Because I need to refresh sites, not items. Should I not be using updateSiteAccountCredentials?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, for site the API is different.

First you would need to call getSiteAccountCredentials or getSiteAccountMfaQuestionsAndAnswers to get login form or MFA QnA as needed, and then updateSiteAccountCredentials.

If the changes worked, refresh would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

To update the credentials you should use [updateSiteAccountCredentials](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/updateSiteAccountCredentials).

But to refresh you should be using startSiteRefresh and check for refresh mode
(`siteRefreshInfo.getSiteRefreshMode()`) if the refresh mode is `MFA_REFRESH_MODE` then you should start the MFA flow.